# Как получить данные, отправленные с React с помощью axios в php файл

Tags: php, reactjs, requests, post, axios

В React компонента я отправляю запрос к php файлу, который находится в одной директории с React приложением (скорее всего это не безопасно, но на этапе разработки будет так). Для отправки использую axios, принимающий в качестве параметра, который нужно отправить, объект values

```
onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting })  {
    setTimeout(() => {
      async function sendDatasAndClearInput() {
        try {
          const response = await axios.post(
            'http://localhost:5173/src/server/login.php',
            values,
            {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
            }
          );
          console.log(values);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
      sendDatasAndClearInput();
      setSubmitting(false);
    }, 400);
}}
```

Так же есть файл php, который должен принять данные с запроса и вывести их.

```
<h1>
    <?php 
        $data = json_decode($_POST['name'], 1);
        echo $data;
    ?> 
</h1>
```

Пробовал и обратиться к php://input

```
<h1>
    <?php 
        $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $input= json_decode( $inputJSON, TRUE ); 
        
        echo json_encode($input);
    ?> 
</h1>
```

Ничего из этого не решило проблему. Подскажите, в чем ошибка

Comment: Если у вас скрипт должен отдавать json, что там тогда вообще забыли html-теги?

Comment: @SemyonBayandin а как тогда вывести переменную, чтобы убедиться в том, что данные успешно переданы ?

Comment: а что мешает это сделать без html-тегов?

Comment: @SemyonBayandin если не вставлять теги, то на странице браузера содержимое файла выводится

Comment: что за бред? Вы точно html-теги убираете? Покажите что вы убираете и что оставляете

Comment: @SemyonBayandin вот весь php: <?php 
        $data = json_decode($_POST['name'], 1);
        echo $data;
    ?>

Comment: А веб-сервер-то у тебя есть? Если в браузере открыть http://localhost:5173/src/server/login.php то что видно?

Comment: @u_mulder localhost от React - сервер. Если убрать html-теги, то выводит черный экран с содержимым документа.

Comment: Веб-сервер - это то, что обрабатывает php-запросы. "localhost от React" это не то что тебе надо. То что тебе надо для локальной разработки - это что-то типа xampp, ну или хотя бы встроенный в php локальный сервер `php -S`.

Comment: Либо если у тебя какой-то "localhost от React" то и пиши тогда серверную часть на джава-скрипте, а не на пыхе.

Comment: @u_mulder "серверная на JS", то есть Node ?

Comment: Ну да, вроде на Ноде.

Comment: Спасибо большое